java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class java.awt.Toolkit on jenkins with jdk1.8 on windows
Getting error on jenkins says:
'java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class java.awt.Toolkit
at com.pypestream.model.page.aaas.InterfacePage.enterCustomCssCode(InterfacePage.java:465)
at com.pypestream.model.page.aaas.InterfacePage$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$c2ab0743.invoke(<generated>)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:771)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:88)
at com.pypestream.aop.AspectLogger.processMethod(AspectLogger.java:54)
at com.pypestream.aop.AspectLogger.logPage(AspectLogger.java:16)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:644)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:633)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:70)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:175)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:95)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:691)
at com.pypestream.model.page.aaas.InterfacePage$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c20d0dcd.enterCustomCssCode(<generated>)
at com.pypestream.test.regressionsuite.Pypes_New_Suit.CSS_ClassName.tc_153789_153791_VerifyThatBotCsvWithCSSClassnameColumnAtTheEndCanBeUploadedInDesignStudio(CSS_ClassName.java:90)
at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1259)
... Removed 34 stack frames

while try to add this data  '(".font_text{\n" + "    font-style: italic;\n" + "}")'
tried with this code it is functioning on local machine not on jenkins
public page enterdataCode(String name) {
    $(".view-lines").shouldBe(Condition.visible).click();
    System.setProperty("java.awt.headless", "false");
    StringSelection stringSelection = new StringSelection(name);
    Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
    clipboard.setContents(stringSelection, null);
    Actions builder = new Actions(WebDriverRunner.getWebDriver());
    builder.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL)
           .sendKeys(Keys.chord("v"))
           .keyUp(Keys.CONTROL)
           .perform();
    System.setProperty("java.awt.headless", "true");
    return this;
}


I'm guessing that Jenkins does not include the java.desktop module.

You can not change the java.awt.headless system property back and forth. Either, your system runs in a headless environment or it does not.

To Holger's point... any browser property must be set BEFORE the browser instance is created.
